# Monitor data usage per app

Tags: networking

I need a software (preferably GUI based), which monitors data usage per application, just like Windows 10's in-built data usage monitor. I've looked at nethogs, but it only shows the transmission rate, not the total amount it has sent or received. May I know if there's any such app?